# Pattern of list contains two types of variables: What is the correct definition?

Tags: pattern-matching

What is the correct form of the pattern "list of variables of two (or more) types"

These examples do not work

```
 MatchQ[{1., "a", 2.3, 7.}, _ {Real | String...}]
```

`False`

```
MatchQ[{1., "a", 2.3, 7.}, _ {_Real | _String...}]
```

`False`

```
MatchQ[{1., "a", 2.3, 7.}, {_Real | _String ...}]
```

`False`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close on the last pattern,

```
In[4]:= MatchQ[{1., "a", 2.3, 7.}, {(_Real | _String) ...}]

Out[4]= True
```

Compare the `FullForm` of the two patterns to see the difference,

```
In[6]:= FullForm[{_Real|_String...}]

Out[6]//FullForm= List[Alternatives[Blank[Real],RepeatedNull[Blank[String]]]]

In[7]:= FullForm[{(_Real|_String)...}]

Out[7]//FullForm= List[RepeatedNull[Alternatives[Blank[Real],Blank[String]]]]
```

Comment: This answer returns `True` also for a `List` of one type (e.g. `Real`). But the question was what is the pattern that returns whether the list has two or more types or not ! means that a list of just one type should not be true.